# IP Multicast - would this work on my dual homed embedded Linux device?

Tags: linux, networking, routes, multicast

I am working on an embedded Linux project.  It has a cell modem that comes up as ppp0 and a single Ethernet interface eth0 that may or may not be connected.  The cable could be unplugged at any time from eth0 or may never be plugged in.

Is it possible to setup multicasting so that it could intelligently send the outgoing traffic over eth0 if it's up, otherwise over ppp0?  If so I would be very interested on how to do this.

Thanks,
Fred

Comment: This is not what multi-casting is about. It's a routing issue. You need some method of detecting that `eth0` is up or down and modifying your routing tables accordingly.

Comment: OK thanks for the comment.  I was given a bit of a red herring today, someone indicated to me that multi-casting could achieve this.